# Trouble rendering lilypond source block in org-babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, lilypond

I am relatively new to org mode and, as someone who enjoys writing about music, i decided to try org-babel-lilypond. I use MacOSx Monterey. I have lilypond installed via Macports, as was recommended in [this thread](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/117623/installing-lilypond-on-big-sur). Lilypond seems to work as a command line interface, but when i try to render a lilypond source block in org-mode I'm met with the following error output:

`/Applications/lilypond.app/Contents/Resources/bin/lilypond: No such file or directory`

Is there a way to configure emacs/org-babel such that it doesn't have to use this directory to render a lilypond block?

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize the variable `org-babel-lilypond-commands`. You can see the variable's doc string with `C-h v org-babel-lilypond-commands` and you can customize it by clicking on the `Customize` link in that doc string. You can then set up how to start `Lilypond`, the `PDF` viewer and the `MIDI` player as appropriate for your system. Then hit `Apply` to set these options for this session. You can try things out and if everything is OK, you can click on `Apply and Save` to save the settings for future sessions.

Comment: It works wonderfully now. Thank you